# Set header HTTP code in Flightphp

Tags: php, flightphp

im developing an API with FlightPHP microframework and I can't set an HTTP response code for my routes.
I can set this and works perfectly:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 500 Error');
```

But I want use the native function http_response_code() from PHP. This one don't do anything.
I want to use this because that I don't have to manually type the error message.

Answer (score 3):

To return a HTTP response code using Flight, you can do it like this :

```
Flight::route('GET /', function(){
    Flight::json($data, $code = 500);
});
```

Where `$data` is the variable that leads to the array you want to send in json.
If `$code` is not set, then the default returned HTTP response code is "200".
https://github.com/mikecao/flight/blob/e25f023d4377a2b99b4be8bf7977f3fc0f8089c8/flight/Engine.php#L500

Answer (score 1):

from flight php

```
 Flight::json($data, [$code], [$encode], [$charset], [$option]) // Sends a JSON response.
    Flight::jsonp($data, [$param], [$code], [$encode], [$charset], [$option]) // Sends a JSONP response.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, to send my own headers, I do so:

```
$code = 404;
Flight->before('stop', function(&$params) use ($code) {
    $params[0] = $code;
});
```